# How to enforce increasing id in Mongo Collection in updating with Java Driver

Tags: java, mongodb

I have the following code that supposed to update or insert a Mongo document if it does not exist

```
ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(b);
o.writeObject(value);
BasicDBObject   doc = new BasicDBObject(“objectData”, getBytesForObject(o))
                .append(“objectKey”, key)
                .append(“LastModified”, mongoDateFormat.format(new Date()));

MongoCollection<BasicDBObject> collection = 
                getMongoDatabase().getCollection("cache", BasicDBObject.class);

UpdateOptions updateOptions = new UpdateOptions();
updateOptions.upsert(true);
collection.updateOne(new BasicDBObject(“objectKey”, key), new BasicDBObject("$set", doc), updateOptions);
```

However, this code always inserts _id as 0.
How to fix this?

Comment: Huh? You seem to have defined something in your code that is not listed here. The `_id` is basically automatically generated ( and is an `ObjectId` and not an integer ) unless do something else. You have other code than this that is the real fault.

Comment: No, that's all code, the only code is not listed is function getBytesForObject